# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor only when test should pass

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In my karma test I have

**controller.js**

```
var somevalue = false;
```

**test.js**

```
expect(somevalue).toBe(true);
```

> This gives me the output: Expected false to equal true.

but if I change the statement to be something that should pass *(changing it to .toBe(false))*.  I get:

**test.js**

```
expect(somevalue).toBe(false);
```

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'angular.element.cleanData(cleanUpNodes)')

Comment: it's hard to say.. but error must be happening after the expect statement, if it fails, then it would show error, but if it passes then it continues and must be facing some other errors down the line.

Comment: @LowFlyingPelican that seemed to be the case, the test was passing but my angular version and angular-mock version were not the same and causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

The test was passing, I just had underlying problems aside from the test. (Angular and Angular-mock versions not matching)